# Java ArrayList: add increment only on non-duplicate

Tags: java

I am trying to increment a counter only after checking that the value is not a duplicate. The code attached is a for loop that is the result of another for loop.

```
    for (UserPoint up : hashMap.get(id)) {

            double upDistance = up.getDistance();

            if (upDistance == 0) {
                String pName = up.getPointName();

                for (String temp : arrayList)
                    if (!(temp.contains(pName))) {
                        arrayList.add(pName);

                        incrementCounter += 1;
                    }
            }
```

these information are to be sent as output to  a csv file. However my incrementCounter value is always 0 in my output. If I changed it to just as below, without checking that the point name is a duplicate, as such:

```
        for (UserPoint up : hashMap.get(id)) {

            double upDistance = up.getDistance();

            if (upDistance == 0) {
                        incrementCounter += 1;
            }
```

it works, but it still increments when on the same point name.

Comment: and what is 'upDistance' ?

Comment: `for (UserPoint up : hashMap.get(id)) {

            double up = lp.getDistance();`  do you see `up` is double and `UserPoint` ..?

Comment: i edited the codes, sorry! @Stultuske

Comment: @Babel my mistake, edited the codes!

Comment: whats the `arrayList` type?

Comment: It's a double... and what does it mean?

Comment: @Satya ArrayList<String>

Comment: @Stultuske the double upDistance is from the up object's get method

Comment: If you are checking for duplicates, and you are not interested in their order, than why not use a Set instead? Or do you want to check if new value is an substring of an already defined value?

Comment: yes, up.getDistance, but distance of/to/... what? what is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I understand that you want to check if pName is already in the arrayList. If that is the case why would you want to use a for loop, instead simply do this:

```
   for (UserPoint up : hashMap.get(id)) {

        double upDistance = up.getDistance();

        if (upDistance == 0) {
            String pName = up.getPointName();


                if (!(arrayList.contains(pName))) {
                    arrayList.add(pName);

                    incrementCounter += 1;
                }
        }
```

**EDIT**

Your code doesn't work because you are checking if pName is a substring of temp which i guess is not what you want to do. You want to check if pName is already present in the list `arrayList`. For this you have to do an `arrayList.contains(pName)`

Comment: May be your answer is good, But OP asks why his solution is not working ??

Comment: thanks! this is what i needed. my code's indeed not working because of your explanation as well. will accept the answer!

Comment: @user3763216 solution is not working as initially ArrayList is empty and so whenever flow comes to it for checking for any item it doesnt get inside of it  on account of being empty. And through out the flow it never gets change to get inside as you are adding element inside the flow. Hence final output is always 0. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

it is because your `arrayList` variable is always empty, and you never enter the second for loop !

you need to do something like this :

```
                boolean found = false;
                for (String temp : arrayList)
                    if (temp.contains(pName)) {
                      found = true;
                      break;
                }
                if (!found) {
                        arrayList.add(pName);

                        incrementCounter += 1;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do, but here is some input: your solution may not be working because of the *inner* for-loop:

```
for (UserPoint up : hashMap.get(id)) {
    double upDistance = up.getDistance();

    if (upDistance == 0) {
        String pName = up.getPointName();

        for (String temp : arrayList)
            if (!(temp.contains(pName))) {
                 arrayList.add(pName);

                 incrementCounter += 1;
            }
     }
```

For each string in the array-list you check if there is a `substring` called `pName`.

Now if you just want to check if (as stated in the title > Java ArrayList: add increment on non-duplicate) it is a duplicate you would just do:

```
if(!arrayList.contains(pName)) {
    arrayList.add(pName);
    incrementCounter += 1;
}
```

If you really want to check for a substring, you *may* want to check both in lowerCase to avoid issues with casing (?)

Like:

```
 for (String temp : arrayList)
      if (!(temp.toLowerCase().contains(pName.toLowerCase()))) {
          arrayList.add(pName);
          incrementCounter += 1;
      }
```

But unless you make clear on what exactly you want to do, both are possible solutions.